# Actionscript and ViewStack = Cannot access a property or method of a null object reference

Tags: apache-flex, actionscript-3, oop

I'm writing a flex program in an OO manner and I've got to the point of creating a ViewStack to hold various panels.  My problem is that when I add a panel to the ViewStack it throws the aforementioned error.  No doubt the answer is pretty obvious so here's the constructor for the manager class that holds my ViewStack.

```
stack = new ViewStack();
loginPanel = new LoginPanel;
regPanel = new RegisterPanel;
stack.creationPolicy = "all";
stack.addChild(loginPanel);
stack.currentState = "loginPanel";
```

Answer (score 3):

I'm not sure why you are setting the `currentState` property of the `ViewStack`. Are you trying to select that child? If so, try using the `selectedChild` property instead. This should work:

```
{
    stack = new ViewStack();

    loginPanel = new LoginPanel();

    regPanel = new RegisterPanel();

    stack.creationPolicy = "all";

    stack.addChild(loginPanel);

    stack.selectedChild = loginPanel;
}
```

Comment: Right, "currentState" is used to select between view states you have defined for a custom component.